# Is there any role of Hashcode() in Serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, hashcode

As per current understanding, The role of hashcode comes with collection like Hashmap, HashSet etc and read there only for practical purposes.

I am being asked that the role of Hashcode in Serialization in an interview.

The answer comes like we can just check whether hashcode is equal after deserialization but interviewer was not satisfied and said google it.

I got following line while googling

> What we must do is to override the `equals()` method and the `hashCode()` method of the original object so they will return true if deserialized instances of the same original object are compared.

Can anyone please provide some practical example which explains role on/of hashcode with serialization?

Comment: Serialization and Deserialization provide identical object ,Hash should be same it is not necessary,Object state would be same means(instance variable will keep same value). If we will go for object hashcode implementation it is a  native method and I think it keep some address from heap reference  so it is quiet practical if we are running JVM  2 times ,JVM may not get heap area at same memory location so when we Deserialize object obviously it may be another location in heap area so Hashcode would be different.

Comment: Your quotation, which I found [here](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp310/JavaResources/RMI/compare.html), is specifically referring to an edge case within RMI. As regards pure serialization over a single stream, the case doesn't exist, because serialization preserves object identity unless `reset()` or `writeUnshared()` is used. This exception also applies across distinct *RMI* calls, which is the actual topic of the Rice lesson. You are correct and the interviewer is wrong, and your Rice University source is not correct on its own without its context.